# MDC Put not showing values in log

Tags: java, logback, mdc

`MDC.put` is not inserting values in the logs.

logback.xml

```
<appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d  [%X{ApigeeId}] [%X{BasePath}] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Code :

```
MDC.put("ApigeeId", apigeeId);
MDC.put("BasePath", "api/crm/sendemi");
```

Logs :

```
2023-01-11 13:13:09,286  [] [] INFO  org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW                             - SlowQuery: 14 milliseconds. SQL: 'HikariProxyPreparedStatement@1852998404 wrapping SQLServerPreparedStatement:12'
```

Getting blank fields.

Tried to check whether values are setting properly by `MDC.get()`, it prints properly.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `<layout>` instead of `<encoder>'?

Comment: Could you detail where you put your parameters in the `MDC`?

Comment: @Faith Im putting values in controller

Comment: @Aakash layout is also not working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use layout
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
  <layout>
    <Pattern>%X{first} %X{last} - %m%n</Pattern>
  </layout> 
</appender>
```